# iframe-resizer: How to scroll to the top

Tags: iframe

how can the iframe be scrolled? In the iframe (on another server) there is already:

```js
if ( 'parentIFrame' in window ) { parentIFrame.scrollTo( 0, 0 ); }
```

But it didn't work. The function inside of "if" is not called.

Comment: Cross Site Scripting (XSS) issue?

Comment: Yes, iframe-Resizer solves this problem. But I still have to learn how to use the scrollTo-Method: https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.parentIFrame.scrollTo(0,0)`